# Semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ is Artinian semisimple. A ring $R$ is said to be semisimple if $J(R)=0$, where $J$ denotes the $\textit{Jacobson radical}$ of $R$.

The Jacobson radical equals the intersection of all maximal ideals of the ring (either left or right but in our case we don't need to worry about that). Now the maximal ideals of  $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ are:  $\mathbb{2Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$, $\mathbb{3Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$, $\mathbb{5Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ and the intersection of those is $\{[0]\}$, thus  $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ is semisimple. The decending sequence of ideals of  $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ are:

$\mathbb{2Z}/\mathbb{30Z} \leq  \mathbb{6Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$; $\mathbb{5Z}/\mathbb{30Z} \leq  \mathbb{10Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$;
 $\mathbb{5Z}/\mathbb{30Z} \leq  \mathbb{15Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$,

thus  $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ satisfies DCC, hence is Artinian.

Is the above correct?

Moreover, I want to write $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}$ as a product of simple rings. I've written:

$\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{30Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}  \times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{5Z}$. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes both are correct. You can also convince yourself the the DCC is trivially satisfied in rings with finitely many ideals, in particular finite rings.
The last statement is simply the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The Wikipedia entry on it is quite good and also tells you how to find the isomorphism if you care to write it down explicitely in both directions.

Comment: There are more descending sequences of ideals, such as
$$2\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}\leq 10\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
3\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}\leq6\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
3\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}\leq15\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}.$$
Also, each sequence can be extended with the ideals $0\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}$ and $1\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}$, and you can take subsequences of these sequences. In stead of listing all sequences, it makes more sense to note that the ring is finite and hence it has only finitely many ideals.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Yes, it definitely makes more sense to argue in the way you both have highlighted instead of trying to list all the descending sequences. Thanks!